# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isupper' Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всем доброго времени суток. Я новичок в Python и учусь по самоучителю. Одна из задач была про декодирования и кодирования шифра. Когда дохожу до isupper выдает ошибку с int. Что надо исправить в коде, и почему? Если найдете ещё ошибки в коде, объясните пожалуйста их тоже. Прикрепляю скрин.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну как бы да, у чисел не бывает метода isupper. Какой результат вы ожидали получить, вызвав isupper у числа?

Comment: Надо не скрин, а код текстом.

Answer (score 0):

Заголовок цикла должен быть таким:

```
for letter in message:
```

Про остальные ошибки что-нибудь смогу сказать, если приложите код текстом.
Но как минимум, последнюю строку следует убрать за цикл.

Картинкой код больше не прикладывайте никогда, это резко снижает шанс на то, что вам помогут.